# Which OpenId Grant Type should I use in MVC application? Code? Client Credentials?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, identitymodel, asp.net-core-5.0

With ASP.NET Core 5, Angular 10 and Identity Server 4 I created 4 applications:

1. Auth using Identity Server 4;
2. Asp.Net Core 5 API
3. Asp.Net Core 5 MVC
4. Angular 10 SPA

On the Angular application (4) I am using [OIDC Client JS](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) and **Code Grant Type**.

The Asp.Net Core 5 MVC application (3) also needs to access the API ...

I am using [Identity Model](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but what Grant Type should I use in MVC application?

**Code** as in the Angular application (Is this possible?)? **Client Credentials**?

Comment: Do you want to call the API on behalf of the signed-in user? Authorization code is your best bet. Or do you want to do the call as the app itself (with no user info in token)? Client credentials.

Comment: In this case on behalf of the application itself. It is just an application to perform some automated tasks. In terms of security both grant type are equally secure?

Comment: No need of using  any grant type in REST API till you do not want to impersonate the user. What API checks is valid token and authorization if enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you login the user on MVC application and you want to call the API on behalf of the user use the `Code` flow.
   In this case only difference between MVC and angular apps is that `Asp.Net Core 5 MVC` is a confidential client and you can use `Code` flow. But `Angular 10 SPA` client is a public client and you should you Code + PKCE.
   It is although recommended to use PKCE in both cases.
2. If you just call an API through MVC and as the app itself and not behalf of the user, you can use Client Credentials flow. This flow is for server to server scenarios and it is secure.
   In this case you should do authorization for MVC app as well.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was really clarifying.